# FFMPEG - Copy a stream with change stream ID

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, codec

I have video files with [.saf] extension.

This file is using for "Seachagne" video server. And can play with MATROX hardware. Problem is, I have to make audio normalization all of these files.

With ffprobe, It detected,

```
Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (High), yuv422p(tv, top first), 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], 10000 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
Stream #0:1[0x2b]: Subtitle: dvd_subtitle
```

I heard that, the stream #0:1 is normal PCM audio stream.
So, I'm trying to copy #0:1 after change stream ID

But, when I tried, ffmpeg says, have to choose an encoder manually.

How can I make it? or, Is there are any idea for that?

Thanks.

Comment: Stream 0:1 is not an audio stream of any type. Unless you have skipped the readouts of other streams, there is no audio stream.

Comment: That's way I'm looking for how to change the stream ID.

This is 24bit UnCompressed PCM audio. 
I attached a link to download the clip. If you have any advice, please let me know.

http://webhdd.eqmaker.kr:8086/share.cgi?ssid=0lhy8IO

Comment: Looks like the audio is a private stream, and tagged correctly as per looking at strings in the file. You could extract all non video packets and concat them and try to interpret them as audio.

Comment: And 302M audio is a *pair* of stereo streams.

Comment: Hi Mulvya. That's right. So I'm looking for a way how to extrect non video packets with ffmpeg. Do you have any advice?

Comment: That can be done. `ffmpeg -c:s text -i file.saf -c:s copy -map 0:s -f data non-video-data.bin` You can then try to parse this output.